# Iterator remove operation doesn't work

Tags: iterator

I get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at onlineShopExamen.Client.remove(Client.java:30)
    at onlineShopExamen.Main.<init>(Main.java:17)
    at onlineShopExamen.Main.main(Main.java:23)`

My code is this:

```
public void remove(){
    Iterator<Product> iter = lijstProducten.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Product movie = iter.next();
        lijstProducten.remove(movie);
    }
}
```

Where Product is a list of products (movies in this case)

Using this:

```
public void remove(){
    Iterator<Product> iter = lijstProducten.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Doesn't work either

That gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
at onlineShopExamen.Client.remove(Client.java:30)
at onlineShopExamen.Main.<init>(Main.java:19)
at onlineShopExamen.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

EDIT *FIXED*

This works:

```
public void remove(){
    Iterator<Product> iter = lijstProducten.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        iter.next();
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's what's called a conservative iterator: as soon as the underlying container is modified any iterator pointing to that container is invalidated (that's what the [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) means).

there is a [`Iterator.remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) method. use it.

```
public void remove(){
    Iterator<Product> iter = lijstProducten.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        iter.next();
        iter.remove(); // removes previous item
    }
}
```

which you can probably (assuming lijstProducten is a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)) also write as mentioned by Ankit

```
public void remove(){
    lijstProducten.clear();
}
```

Comment: public void remove(){
  Iterator<Product> iter = lijstProducten.iterator();
  while(iter.hasNext()){
   iter.remove();
   }
 }

I did this^

Still get the same error :/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Beyeler's answer. As I see from your code, your `remove` method is clearing the whole list.

I would suggest you to use the method `myList.clear();` to remove all the elements from a list instead of making your own method.

Answer (score 0):

Try iter.remove() instead of lijstProducten.remove(movie). You cannot modify the list youre iterating but theres remove method in Iterator that will do it for you.